# Where does CSS look for fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I have an HTML which uses the Helvetica Neue font for most of the text.

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Calibri, sans-serif; 
<font color="#ffffff" face="'Helvetica Neue Medium','Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Sample text</font>
```

Using [Fount](http://fount.artequalswork.com/) I can see that the text is actually written using Helvetica Neue Medium.

My question is where does the css/html look for this font ? I checked my /Windows/Fonts folder and there is no Helvetica font there.

Comment: Have you included some external file for font or you just assigned 'Helvetica Neue' in the property? You can add custom fonts in number of ways. If that font is present in machine's `font` directory, it will be applied. If none of the specified fonts were present then it will include any `sans-serif`, `serif` or `monospace` font as specified in the property.

Comment: there is no external font/file. I got (just) the html like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS will look for fonts installed in your font directory.

We can configure fonts with *@font-face* rule

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyHelvetica;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Medium"),
   local("HelveticaNeue-Medium"),
   url(HelveticaNeueMedium.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: There is no such thing in my html file and when I got the html it was just the html, no other external file. So how come it is able to use the font when the font is not in my font directory ?

Comment: It can be included via scripts also like google fonts/ adobe fonts ref : https://www.google.com/fonts, http://www.adobe.com/type/fontfinder/

Comment: Do you have Helvetica Neue Medium installed in your system ?

Comment: I don't think I do. There is no helvetica in my c:/windows/fonts folder. can it be anywhere else ?

Comment: Please check in style sheets in your html file for @font-face. Is there is any scripts to load external resources? If there is it would be loaded from external source. eg: google-font api load fonts from externally via css loaded with scripts.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that the tool I was using to check the font was not that good after all, and it was using Arial :(